# Get forms with DomCrawler in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5, domcrawler

I'm working with Laravel 5.2 Commands and trying to get a form with Symfony component DomCrawler.
So, with the help of DomCrawler [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/3.3/components/dom_crawler.html#forms) and [api](http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Form.html), I have this code:

```
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;
```

And, in handle() method:

```
$fake_body = '<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row search-filtro" style="    margin-top: 10px;">
            <form id="search_form" action="http://somesite.com/">

                <select class="form-control" id="slc_region" name="slc_region" form="form_busqueda" >
                    <option value="default" disabled selected style="display: none;">Ciudad</option>
                    <option value="default">Todo</option>
                    <option value="1">Región Metropolitana</option>
                    <option value="2">XV Arica y Parinacota</option>
                </select>

                <select class="form-control" id="slc_tipo" name="slc_tipo" form="form_busqueda" >
                    <option value="default" disabled selected style="display: none;">Categoría</option>
                    <option value="default">Todo</option><option value="Tiempo Libre">Tiempo Libre</option>
                    <option value="Otros">Otros</option><option value="Tecnología">Tecnología</option>
                    <option value="Salud, Deporte y Belleza">Salud, Deporte y Belleza</option>
                    <option value="Mi Casa">Mi Casa</option><option value="Infantil">Infantil</option>
                    <option value="Vestuario y Calzado">Vestuario y Calzado</option>
                </select>

                <input type="text" id="buscar_inp" name="buscar_inp" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar Comercio..." >

                <button type="button" id="buscar_btn" class="btn btn-search btn-lg col-sm-12">BUSCAR</button>

            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
';
$site = new Crawler( $fake_body );
$form = $site->filter('form')->form();
```

Im programing this in Laravel Command, so when I run this in console with `php artisan scrap-site`, my script stops with this message error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Current URI must be an absolute URL ("").
```

I already try setting action attribute of form with a relative url, absolute url, http, https, and deleting attribute but always is the same error.

Catching and tracing error message, I found in `vendor/symfony/dom-crawler/AbstractUriElement.php` folder the abstract class **AbstractUriElement** and the error is in __construct method.

```
/**
 * @param \DOMElement $node       A \DOMElement instance
 * @param string      $currentUri The URI of the page where the link is embedded (or the base href)
 * @param string      $method     The method to use for the link (get by default)
 *
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException if the node is not a link
 */
public function __construct(\DOMElement $node, $currentUri, $method = 'GET')
{
    if (!in_array(strtolower(substr($currentUri, 0, 4)), array('http', 'file'))) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Current URI must be an absolute URL ("%s").', $currentUri));
    }

    $this->setNode($node);
    $this->method = $method ? strtoupper($method) : null;
    $this->currentUri = $currentUri;
}
```

Make an echo for `$currentUri` param, it's empty!! :(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply by adding `root` url to the crawler, you should be fine

```
$fake_body = '<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row search-filtro" style="    margin-top: 10px;">
            <form id="search_form" action="http://somesite.com/">

                <select class="form-control" id="slc_region" name="slc_region" form="form_busqueda" >
                    <option value="default" disabled selected style="display: none;">Ciudad</option>
                    <option value="default">Todo</option>
                    <option value="1">Región Metropolitana</option>
                    <option value="2">XV Arica y Parinacota</option>
                </select>

                <select class="form-control" id="slc_tipo" name="slc_tipo" form="form_busqueda" >
                    <option value="default" disabled selected style="display: none;">Categoría</option>
                    <option value="default">Todo</option><option value="Tiempo Libre">Tiempo Libre</option>
                    <option value="Otros">Otros</option><option value="Tecnología">Tecnología</option>
                    <option value="Salud, Deporte y Belleza">Salud, Deporte y Belleza</option>
                    <option value="Mi Casa">Mi Casa</option><option value="Infantil">Infantil</option>
                    <option value="Vestuario y Calzado">Vestuario y Calzado</option>
                </select>

                <input type="text" id="buscar_inp" name="buscar_inp" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar Comercio..." >

                <button type="button" id="buscar_btn" class="btn btn-search btn-lg col-sm-12">BUSCAR</button>

            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
';

$site = new Crawler( $fake_body, 'http://my-project.dev/' );
$form = $site->filter('form')->form();
```

Comment: Two days struggling with this and you help me in ten minutes. Thank you, very much, bro